# how to do autocomplete in angular 7 smart table with dynamic data?

Tags: angular7, ng2-smart-table

when i'm trying to edit/create data in smart table how to auto fill the data in the cell. I tried with completer but it is showing me no results.

```
export const  dataTable = [];
  export  const dataTablesettings ={
    hideheaders: true,
    actions: {
        add:true,
        edit:true,
        delete:true,
        columnTitle: 'Actions',
    },
  noDataMessage: 'No data found',
    columns: {
        ItemCode: {
        title: 'Code',
        type: 'string',
        filter: true,
        editable: true,
        editor: {
          type: 'completer',
          config: {
            completer: {
              data: dataTable,
              searchFields: 'ItemCode',
              titleField: 'ItemCode',
            },
          },
        }
      },
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the magic of `ng2-smart-table`. The main advantage of that is the filled data when you want to edit data with inline edit feature.

While edit, It is the default feature of `ng2-smart-table` is to fill row's data. If you are unable to show data that mean you are missing something.

In a matter of create, When you clicked on save button you have use it's `(onCreate)="saveData(event)"` method.

In `.ts` file

```
saveData(event){
    event.confirm.resolve(); // This will add new data on top of the data. 
}
```